# Zend Framework 2 tutorial: Module (Application) could not be initialized

Tags: zend-framework2

I am following the official Zend Framework 2 tutorial for version 2.1. In the [Unit Testing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html) section, where I am supposed to run phpunit in module/Application/test I am running into the following problem:

```
user@xubuntu1210:~/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/module/Application/test$ phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/module/Application/test/phpunit.xml.dist

E

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.00Mb

There was 1 error:

1) ApplicationTest\Controller\IndexControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Application) could not be initialized.

/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:140
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:81
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:460
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:204
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:100
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:239
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:146
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:173
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:193
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:236
/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/module/Application/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/IndexControllerTest.php:20

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I copied the contents of IndexControllerTest.php from the tutorial.

```
<?php

namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class IndexControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            include '/home/user/Desktop/zf2-tutorial/config/application.config.php'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/'); // this is line 20
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);

        $this->assertModule('application');
        $this->assertControllerName('application_index');
        $this->assertControllerClass('IndexController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('home');
    }
}
```

I have no clue why the application won't initialize and I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: My problem was the permissions I had in my module folder and files. (I'm in a Ubuntu PC)

Answer (score 35):

This is an autoloading problem that may be related with the `module_paths` option in `config/application.config.php` (in the tutorial, it's the one you have in `/path/to/application/config/test/application.config.php`).

That `application.config.php` probably looks like following:

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',
    ),

    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

To fix your problem, change the value `./module` into an absolute path, for example `__DIR__ . '/../module`, assuming the `application.config.php` is in `config/` in your application's root dir.

To clarify: the problem occurs because `./module` is a path relative to your `cwd`. Your `cwd` when running `phpunit` is inside the test dir, where there isn't (obviously) any `module` dir.

Comment: Thanks for you response @Ocramius I did try this but I get `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ApplicationTest\Controller\IndexControllerTest::assertModule() in /var/www/test/zf2-tutorial/module/Application/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/IndexControllerTest.php on line 22` not sure if its solving one issue and causing another.

Comment: Well, the issue seems to be solved there (`IndexControllerTest::assertModule` does not exist is another issue). We can chat about that.

Comment: Seems it should be `assertModuleName` for everyones reference looks like quite a lot still needs updating in this user guide.

Comment: Yes, it needs a lot of work so far. If you find such horrid mistakes, please DO edit them live on Github eventually (link is on the docs sidebar)

Comment: Thank you!  Changing assertModule to assertModuleName gets me past the crash... but now I find that I can't get the test to pass.  (Controller name is application\controller\index instead of application\index)  Is that because I've actually done something wrong, or is this another error in the tutorial code?

Comment: The controller name is what you have configured in `$config['controllers']['invokables']` (usually). That one is the name you assigned to the controller service.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @Ocramius think that means another update in the user-guide in that case. So it matches up with the default in the Skeleton config.

Answer (score -1):

Check the application.config file in Root config folder where we have to define the applications in 'modules'.

Sample code:

```
'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'FrontEnd',
              ),
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it. In my config/application.config.php I have `'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',
    ),
`