# Zend Framework 2 on 1&1

Tags: php, apache, module, zend-framework2, skeleton-code

I'm setting up Zend Framework 2 on a 1&1 shared hosting site following the [skeleton application tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html), and I'm having issues with the application module not loading:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message
'Module (Application) could not be initialized.' in /homepages/etc/etc/etc/zendskeletonapplication-master/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:175
```

I found someone with the [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768621/zend-framework-2-tutorial-module-application-could-not-be-initialized), but they're only getting it in unit testing, and I'm getting it when loading the site itself. Nonetheless, I've tried changing the `module_paths` settings as described there but the error doesn't change.

I'm guessing this is some sort of 1&1-specific issue with module loading. To get things this far I've already had to add a `.htaccess` with these settings (which sets the server to use PHP 5.4.16, despite the mention of "php6"):

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php
AddType x-mapp-php6 .php
```

Comment: I highly doubt that 1&1 is running PHP6

Comment: As mentioned in my original comment, those are the settings they require to use PHP 5.4. They explain why on [this page](http://faq.1and1.co.uk/scripting/php/5.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a 1&1 issue.  This issue usually occurs when you have something incorrectly set up in the module.

Check the following files to make sure they exist and are set up correctly. It looks like you are using the skeleton app tutorial so make sure the following files match exactly:

> /module/Application/Module.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

---

> /module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your post! I checked those files, and while their _contents_ matched exactly, their file name casing did _not_.

It turns out that 1&1 has an alias in bash (SSH) defined for unzip (I triple-checked my aliases to ensure it wasn't from one of my aliases) of "unzip -L", which makes everything it extracts lowercase. I just extracted on my local machine and uploaded the files instead, and everything was up and running in moments. :)