# Zend Framework 2: Uncaught Exception - Module can't be initialized

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, runtime-error, callstack

I'm new to using **ZF2**, and running into an issue getting the first project I need to work on set up locally. I've gone through and set up the application locally, but when I try to access the home page I receive the following exception error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module
>   (Application) could not be initialized.' in
>   /var/www/myproject/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php
>   on line 140
>
> Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Application)
>   could not be initialized. in
>   /var/www/myproject/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php
>   on line 140

There is also some output being echoed from a Call Stack trace.. not sure if it will be helpful in resolving this:

```
getApplication()->getEventManager(); $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener(); $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager); $this->initDatabase($e); } public function initDatabase($e) { Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')); } public function getConfig() { return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php'; } public function getServiceConfig() { return array( 'factories' => array( 'dbadapter' => new Zfe\Factory('db'), ), ); } public function getAutoloaderConfig() { return array( 'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array( 'namespaces' => array( __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__, ), ), ); } }
```

An image with the full stack trace and errors:
[image]

There was a very similar question already posted about this topic: [Zend Framework 2 tutorial: Module (Application) could not be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768621/zend-framework-2-tutorial-module-application-could-not-be-initialized) .

Reading through that posting I followed the suggested answers recommendations of setting an absolute path for **module_paths** within `application.config.php`, however this did not affect my problem.

`application.config.php` excerpt:

> ```
> 'module_paths' => array(
>         __DIR__.'/../module',
>         './vendor',
>     ),
> ```

```
<?
namespace Application;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;

use Model;
use Zfe;

class Module implements  ServiceProviderInterface { 
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $this->initDatabase($e);
}        

public function initDatabase($e) {        
    Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
}

public function getConfig() {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
            'factories' => array(
                    'dbadapter'    => new Zfe\Factory('db'),
            ),
    );
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
}
```

Any insight as to where I could look to start debugging this would be much appreciated!

Comment: do you have a file at `module/Application/Module.php`? If yes, assuming you've not modified it, are there any differences in the first 20 lines between your version and https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/Module.php?

Comment: Yes the file is there. There are a few additions to the class in my project that are not in the skeletonApp class. I will post the additional contents of the class I am using.

Comment: Okay well `<?` on the first line should be `<?php` unless you have specifically enabled `short_open_tag` on your server. That's probably all it is.

Comment: HAHAHA! Seriously! Yes, I have short_open_tags disabled on my localhost. Didn't even catch that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the error indicates ZF couldn't find the module class. In this case it is because a short open tag is being used (`<?` instead of `<?php`). PHP code being output is generally a good indicator of this.