# How can i initialized Module (User) in ZF3?

Tags: zend-framework3

I am trying to run Hello world in ZendFramework3 localhost but getting issue..

/Documents/zen/path/to/install$ php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public public/index.php

PHP 7.2.17-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3 Development Server started at Thu Apr 25 17:15:10 2019
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000

```php
/home/Documents/zen/path/to/install/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:203
Stack trace:
#0 /home/Documents/zen/path/to/install/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(175): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

#1 /home/Documents/zen/path/to/install/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(97): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('User')

#2 /home/Documents/zen/path/to/install/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

#3 /home/Documents/zen/path/to/install/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

#4 /home/ in /home/Documents/zen/path/to/install/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 203
```

please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please make sure to follow guidelines set out in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you can find what you're looking for with a simple "zend framework initialize module" google search, e.g. https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Creating_a_New_Module/How_to_Create_a_New_Module_.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 tutorial: Module (Application) could not be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768621/zend-framework-2-tutorial-module-application-could-not-be-initialized)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a module (User), you must :

- add your module namespace in `config/modules.config.php`
- add your module namespace  and path in `composer.json`, section `autoload/psr-4` (the path must end with "/")
- run `composer dump-autoload` to update yours vendor/composer/... files